# Use ValueGeneratedOnAdd with complex type

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, type-conversion, type-mapping

Lets say you have a complex type:

```
public class Identity<TEntity> : IEquatable<Identity<TEntity>>
{
    public Identity(Guid value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public Guid Value { get; }


    public static implicit operator Guid(Identity<TEntity> identity)
    {
        return identity.Value;
    }

    public static explicit operator Identity<TEntity>(Guid value)
    {
        return new Identity<TEntity>(value);
    }
}
```

How to configure a type using this complex type as Id, e.g.

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public Identity<TEntity> Id { get; }
}
```

within a type configuration for ef core?

For example a type configuration like:

```
public class MyEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntity>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MyEntity> builder)
    {
       var converter = new ValueConverter<Identity<MyEntity>, Guid>(
           v => v.Value,
           v => new Identity<MyEntity>(v));

       builder.HasKey(e => e.Id);
       builder.Property(e => e.Id)
           .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
           .HasConversion(converter);
    }
}
```

will produce an empty Guid (no values generated).

Answer (score 0):

You have a constructor which set the Value. In order to get a value you need to set a value like below.

```
Identity<Gibra> identity = new Identity<Gibra>(Guid.NewGuid());
```

Or you have a empty constructor

```
public class Identity<TEntity> : IEquatable<Identity<TEntity>>
{
    Guid _value = Guid.NewGuid();
    public Identity(Guid value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public Identity()
    {
        
    }

    public Guid Value { get { return _value; } set { _value = value; } }

    public bool Equals(Identity<TEntity> other)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static implicit operator Guid(Identity<TEntity> identity)
    {
        return identity.Value;
    }

    public static explicit operator Identity<TEntity>(Guid value)
    {
        return new Identity<TEntity>(value);
    }
}
```

So that you can use like this

```
Identity<Gibra> identity = new Identity<Gibra>();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not address .ValueGeneratedOnAdd() which results in server side generation (or by driver on client side). Your aproach is valid but ignores ValueGeneratedOnAdd and moves this instead into the object and is always generating this in the client.